# Using Groovy to capture the last day of the previous month

Tags: groovy, boomi

I'm using Groovy(1.5) in Boomi to capture the last day of the previous month, and I've been mixing some things I found via Google:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.InputStream;

for( int i = 0; i < dataContext.getDataCount(); i++ ) {
    InputStream is = dataContext.getStream(i);
    Properties props = dataContext.getProperties(i);

    dataContext.storeStream(is, props);
}

var dt = new Date(); 
dt.setDate(1);  
dt.setHours(-1); 

props.setProperty("document.dynamic.userdefined.StartDate",dt);
```

But I'm being met with the following error:

```
No signature of method: com.sun.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngine.var() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.Date) values: {Thu Feb 25 16:09:33 UTC 2021} (in groovy script);
 Caused by: No signature of method: com.sun.script.groovy.GroovyScriptEngine.var() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.Date) values: {Thu Feb 25 16:09:33 UTC 2021}
```

Comment: Properties are strings so you need to convert to one before using `setProperty()`.

Comment: FYI, that's not the error you'll get if you miss an import.  That would be a ClassNotFoundException (or related).  When you get a "no signature of method" that means that there's no method that takes arguments of the types you're sending it.  In this case, a type of java.util.Date.

Comment: something like `String newdt = dt.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ");` then pas in newdt instead of dt.

Answer (score 0):

`var` is a JavaScript reserved keyword. Two ways to fix this error:

1. Use JavaScript as Language:

   [image]
2. Replace `var` with `def`:

   ```
   def dt = new Date();
   dt.setDate(1);
   dt.setHours(-1);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The below example shows how to get the last day of the previous month and format as:

- Date
- Day of month
- Short name of the day
- Full name of the day

.

The main trick is subtracting the Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH from the current date which will always provide the last day of the previous month.

.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
def date = new Date();

date = date.minus(date.getAt(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

def ddmmyyyyDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
def dayShortNameDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E");
def dayFullNameDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");

println "Date of last day of previous month: " + ddmmyyyyDateFormat.format(date);
println "Last day of previous month: " + date.getAt(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
println "Short name of day: " + dayShortNameDateFormat.format(date);
println "Full name of day: " + dayFullNameDateFormat.format(date);
```